# maximum subsets of a certain type contained in difference set

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, additive-combinatorics

Explaining my question in words doesn't really make sense. I'll  define a few concepts first.

for a set $S  \subseteq \mathbb{Z} $, define $||S||=\{|s| : s \in S ,\   |s|>0\}$ i.e. the set obtained by taking the absolute value of everything in $S$ and throwing away the element 0.

Also, For two sets $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ define their difference as the set $S_{1}-S_{2}=\{s_{1}-s_{2} : s_{1}\in S_{1},\ s_{2}\in S_{2}\}$

Here is the question:

Let $S  \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$  such that for any distinct $s_{1},s_{2} \in S$,  $|s_{1}-s_{2}|\notin S$ i.e. $||S-S||\cap S=\emptyset$. and define the complement of $S$ as $S^c=\{1,\dots ,n\} \setminus S$

I am wondering about  $\max_ {H \subseteq S^c} \{|H| : ||H-H|| \subseteq S^c \}$. That is, given these constraints on $S$, I want to know the maximum size of a subset $H$ of $S^c$ where $||H-H||\subseteq S^c $

I am also interested in the expected size of this maximum subset $H$ given $n$ and $|S|$  and sets $S$ that minimize this. It is fairly simple to show that $|H|>|S|-1$ by considering the set $||S-s^*||$ where $s^*$ is the minimum element of $S$, but I am hoping to do better than this.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.